# Integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K\left(x\right)\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx=-4\ln2$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider the Elliptical Integral of the First Kind:
$$K\left(k\right)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^{2}\sin^{2}t}}dt$$
then,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K\left(x\right)\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx\stackrel{?}=-4\ln2$$

I was working on Integrals of similar form and I decided to check some values in Integer Relation Algorithms and unexpectedly this came up.


It can be converted to the following Series Representation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{(2n-1)2^{4n}}=2\left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\ln2$$
or the equivalent,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{2H_{2n}-H_n-2\ln2}{(2n-1)2^{4n}}=2\left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\ln2$$

I am aware of the techniques required to solve these Series but this seems like a round about way to solve the Original Integral.


That's why I am looking for a possibly straightforward evaluation of the Integral.

Comment: There is an antiderivative

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for the Comment! I somehow missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Your integral can be written as:
$$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(k)\log{(\cos{k})}}{\sin^2{k}\sqrt{-\sin^2{k}\sin^2{x}+1}}dkdx,$$
then if you think on this double integral you must get:
$$I=-4\log{2}-2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos{x}dx+2,$$
and conclude $I=-4\log{2}$.

---

Playing with these type of integrals others sums involving harmonic numbers can be obtained:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\binom{2n}{n}^2H_{n}(4n^3+3n-1)}{2^{5n}(2n-1)^2}=\frac{\Gamma{(1/4)}^2}{2\pi^{3/2}}\tag{1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the Answer!

Comment: @User Just for info, the value $\dfrac{\Gamma(1/4)^2}{2\pi^{3/2}}$ is the _reciprocal_ of the [ubiquitous constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ubiquitous+constant+).