# Integrals involving the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, elliptic-integrals

**Context**

This question is related to [Integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K\left(x\right)\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx=-4\ln2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782948/integral-int-01-frack-leftx-right-ln-left1-x2-rightx2dx-4/4783002#4783002). But deals with the following generalization.

Being: $$F(\phi,k)=\int_{0}^{\phi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}},$$ the incomplete elliptic of the first kind.
Consider:
$$I(\phi)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos{k}\log{(\cos{k})}F(\phi,\sin{k})}{\sin^2{k}} \tag{1}dk.$$
We have seen in the linked question:
$$I(\pi/2)=-4\log{2}.\tag{2}$$
But we have also:
$$I(\pi/3)=\frac{\pi}{6}-\log{(2+\sqrt{3})}\tag{3},$$

$$I(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{8}-\log{(1+\sqrt{2})}-\frac{\sqrt{2}\log{2}}{4},\tag{4}$$
$$I(\pi/5)=-\log{\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}}+1\right)}+\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}} \right)\log{(1+\sqrt{5})}+\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{8}} -2\right)\log{2}+\pi\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}}{20}+\frac{1}{20}},\tag{5}$$
$$I(\pi/8)
=\log{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+4}-\sqrt{2}-2}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+4}}\right) -\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{16}} }\log{(1+\sqrt{2})}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{32}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{64}}\log{2}+\pi\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{256}+\frac{1}{128}}.\tag{6}$$
**Question**

Does anybody know if $I(\phi)$ has series representations when $\phi \neq \pi/2$? The purpose is to obtain some series for these cases if its possible. Thanks for your cooperation!

Comment: Using [this series](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.5#E4_1) for $F(\phi,k)$ and interchanging the sum and integral I believe you'd only be left with an integral that reduces to a derivative of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm not so sure about your claim.

Comment: @User Given the incomplete elliptic integral $F(\phi,k)$, would you happen to know any closed-form value (maybe involving $\Gamma(x)$ or $\text{log}(x)$) when $\phi \neq \pi/2$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I'm working on it buy still I haven't arrived to any closed-form value.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Mathematica`notations
$$\int_{0}^{\phi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(x)}}=F\left(\phi \left|k^2\right.\right)$$ if

$$0<\Re(\phi
   )\leq \frac{\pi }{2}\lor -\frac{\pi }{2}\leq \Re(\phi )<0$$

If you are concerned by small values of $\phi$, *may be*, you could use
$$F\left(\phi \left|k^2\right.\right)=\phi+k^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{P_n(k)}{(2n+1)!}\, \phi^{2n+1}$$ where the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(k) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 9 k^2-4 \\
 3 & 225 k^4-180 k^2+16 \\
 4 & 11025 k^6-12600 k^4+3024 k^2-64 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and use
$$\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2}\frac{\cos(k)\log{(\cos(k))}}{\sin^2(k)} \,\,\sin^{2n}(k) \,dk=-\frac 1{2n-1 }\,\,H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: By coincidence, since I just considered the incomplete gamma function $\Gamma{(a,x)} $, I've also been 'looking at the incomplete elliptic integral $F(\phi,k)$. For the latter, do you know any closed-form value when $\phi \neq \pi/2$?